# Interpreting an estimated bivariate VECM

Tags: r, interpretation, cointegration, intercept, vector-error-correction-model

I have used the `tsDyn` package in R to estimate a VEC model for the data in the graph, and I am unsure about my interpretation of the output.

[image]

```r
> m1=VECM(data=cbind(X,Y), lag=1, estim="ML"); summary(m1)
#############
###Model VECM 
#############
Full sample size: 120   End sample size: 118
Number of variables: 2  Number of estimated slope parameters 8
AIC 786.5118    BIC 811.448     SSR 14054.05
Cointegrating vector (estimated by ML):
    X          Y
r1  1 -0.8485113


           ECT                 Intercept         X -1              Y -1              
Equation X -1.1403(0.2037)***  7.4572(1.4838)*** 0.4345(0.1926)*   -0.2085(0.2240)    
Equation Y -0.2891(0.1792)     2.2537(1.3054).   0.0577(0.1694)     0.0430(0.1971)
```

I think this means the following (rounding all numbers to two decimals):
\begin{aligned}
\Delta X_t &= 7.46-1.14(X_{t-1}-0.85Y_{t-1})+0.43\Delta X_{t-1}-0.21\Delta Y_{t-1}+u_t, \\
\Delta Y_t &= 2.25-0.29(X_{t-1}-0.85Y_{t-1})+0.06\Delta X_{t-1}+0.04\Delta Y_{t-1}+v_t.
\end{aligned}

**Question:** Have I interpreted the `Intercept` correctly? I do not think so: the time trend in $X$ certainly does not have a slope of $7.45$. The increase in $X$ is from around $85$ to around $145$ in $120$ time periods, implying a slope of $0.5$. A similar discrepancy is also true for $Y$. (The documentation of the `VECM` function does not explain what `Intercept` means.)

Answer (score 0):

The intercept does not seem to be applicable to the VECM (there should be none) but to the equivalent VAR representation instead:

```r
> VARrep(m1)
constant       X.l1      Y.l1        X.l2        Y.l2
X 7.457166  0.2942115 0.7590182 -0.43451215  0.20853976
Y 2.253700 -0.2313316 1.2882556 -0.05772787 -0.04298536
```

\begin{aligned}
X_t &= 7.46+0.29 X_{t-1} + 0.76 Y_{t-1} + 0.43 X_{t-2} - 0.21 Y_{t-2} + u_t, \\
Y_t &= 2.25-0.23 X_{t-1} + 1.29 Y_{t-1} - 0.06 X_{t-2} - 0.04 Y_{t-2} + v_t.
\end{aligned}

So the VECM actually is the same as before but without the itercepts:
\begin{aligned}
\Delta X_t &= 1.14(X_{t-1}-0.85Y_{t-1})+0.43\Delta X_{t-1}-0.21\Delta Y_{t-1}+u_t, \\
\Delta Y_t &= 0.29(X_{t-1}-0.85Y_{t-1})+0.06\Delta X_{t-1}+0.04\Delta Y_{t-1}+v_t.
\end{aligned}

I hope this is correct.

Comment: What are your typical levels of the spread $x_{t-1} - .85 y_{t-1}$ and the deltas? If you plug in sensible numbers for the whole thing $7.46-1.14(X_{t-1}-0.85Y_{t-1})+0.43\Delta X_{t-1}-0.21\Delta Y_{t-1}$, does that give you roughly $\Delta x_t$? The spread is probably not mean zero. You could reparameterize in terms of a spread shift and that might make more sense.

Comment: @Taylor, if I plug in sensible values to this equation, all the terms are quite small, so I get a number close to $7.46$. That does not make much sense to me, but I think I have solved the problem now by noticing that the intercept is meant for the VAR representation, not the VECM.